# How to use modifiers in Blend4Web

Tags: export, wireframe, blend4web

I've been trying to export a wireframe (wire material assigned) object in HTML with Blend4web and it won't work. Am I doing something wrong, or is it not possible to do? Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the wireframe modifier without applying it. Just set checkbox on "Apply modifier" in the object settings on your model and the engine will do it automatically during export, so you can more easily modify your mesh in Blender if you leave the wireframe modifier on it.

Answer (score 1):

A wireframe material is now fairly easy to make in Cycles, but this isn't supported yet in Blend4Web.

So the easiest way around this would be to [use the wireframe modifier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=looavSCcluU), which does seem to work well. You just need to *apply* the modifier, then save your scene and export to Blend4Web.

[image: Wire in Blend4Web]

You can probably do this by baking the wireframe color in cycles and using the baked image as a transparency map, but that's a longer, more complicated solution.

Comment: Why do you say modifiers aren't supported in Blend4Web? Actually, you don't even need to apply the modifier - you can navigate to the Object Context, and listed under *Export Options* there is an option you can tick to "Apply Modifiers". *(This is only visible while the render engine is set to Blend4Web)* ;-) (Edit: Never mind, user Blend4Web already pointed this out in their answer.)